# How do I extract the values of the first element of a JSON file?

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

Ok so I have this JSON file here: https://api.tvmaze.com/shows/25376/episodes, which is basically just a list, and each item in the list is a dictionary. I want to get all the values of the first element of this list but I am having some issues figuring it out.

```
import json

with open('snakes.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

for dictionary in data:

    for value in dictionary.values():

        print(value)
```

My code here prints out all the values of all the dictionaries of the JSON file, but I just want all the values of the first dictionary or the first element so to speak.

I tried the following:

```
for dictionary in data[0]:

    for value in dictionary.values():

        print(value)
```

But this just gives me an error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'
```

Comment: Drop the first for-loop and replace "dictionary.values()" by "data[0].values()"

Comment: That works. Can you explain why my attempted solution doesn't work, or why I get that AttributeError.

Comment: `for dictionary in data[0]:` will iterate through your keys in first object. Because all the keys are `string` objects, they don't have attribute `values`, and throw the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Just change to:

```py
dictionary = data[0]
for value in dictionary.values():
    print(value)
```